# Undefined variable from PHP to AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I need to take some variables from PHP to AS3, but this is not working.

AS3 Code:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("link.php");
var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables;

urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = urlVariables;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlCompleted);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

function urlCompleted(event:Event):void{
    var urlLoaderOk:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    urlLoaderOk.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    trace(urlLoaderOk.data.resultVar);
}
```

and this is the simple PHP Code:

```
<?php
print "resultVar=okay";
?>
```

I'm getting "undefined" result.

However, if I try

```
trace(urlLoaderOk.data);
```

like this, I'm getting this result

```
%3C%3Fphp%0D%0Aprint%20%22resultVar=okay%22%3B%0D%0A%3F%3E
```

Comment: the same problem with using `echo "resultVar=okay"`?

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP code isn't interpreted as PHP, resulting in the whole files content to be returned (try to URL decode the data string), which of course isn't valid.

So, check what's wrong with your server, maybe it doesn't support PHP, maybe PHP is disabled, maybe the `.php` extension isn't registered (that would be pretty weird though), maybe you're actually not testing this on a server at all, but in your local filesystem, etc...

Comment: I've checked link.php and It is opening in the browser and showing "resultVar = okay" so there is a no problem, I guess.

Comment: @ssorfonos Since a webserver doesn't really care about from where a request originates, you are most probably not loading the file from the server, as I mentioned, you might not be running your movie on/from the server, but in your local filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried with full url like "http://some.where.com/location/of/link.php" in URLRequest ?
and also try this code

```
function urlCompleted(event:Event):void{
    var urlLoaderOk:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
   var urlvars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(urlLoaderOk.data);
    trace(urlvars.resultVar);
}
```